# Jenkins TFS plugin fails behind proxy

Tags: tfs, jenkins, windows-server-2008, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying for sometime to get the TFS plugin working, and have had "semi" success.

The parts of the process that use Team Explorer command line client work well (I have defined the TFSPROXY environment variable, which seems to work.)

As soon as the plugin gets to the piece that uses the SDK, I get a stack trace printed, with the main error:

```
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Unknown host somehost.on.corporate.network.
```

I have tried using the environment variables: HTTP_PROXY, and TFSPROXY. I have also tried adding the registry keys at HKLM/Software/MS/VisualStudio/10.0/TeamFoundation/SourceControl/Proxy (also added v9.0).

My question is: Is there any way to configure proxy settings for the SDK that the plugin is using, or has someone else had success with another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who may be having this issue, I found that it is only the latest versions of the plugin using the SDK (3.0+), and the previous versions (2.0 and less) are using only the command line tool.

So as a workaround, I have downgraded to 2.0 and everything seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: major-mann, many thanks for the workaround! It's a pity had to downgrade though...

Comment: Could you detail what version of TFS and TEECLC you are using? The plugin unfortunately does not have a dependency matrix.